# Jaunt Java response error POST request

Tags: java, post, http-post

I am trying to send a POST request via Jaunt `sendPost()` method.

To test my requests, I use a nice addon for Firefox, so I know they are valid.

I use the same exact Request Body and URL as the addon, but I still get error 404.

Here is the error log. No code needed here.

```
Exception in thread "main" message: UserAgent.doPOST; response error
requestUrl: http://www.urlgoesinhere.com/shop
response: 
  requestURL: http://www.urlgoesinhere.com/shop [posting commit=add+to+basket&size=41864&style=20263]
  cached: false
  status: 404
  message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<title>Supreme</title>
<meta content="Hello there" name="description" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
<meta content="on" http-equiv="cleartype" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/" />
<link href="//d17oldwd63kd3.cloudfront.net/assets/application-6a6525f1acf65b7949c97c3a7.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="home">
    <header id="header">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="logo">Aldo</h1>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <div id="wrap" class="wrap-404">
        <p>This page cannot be found</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
  responseHeaders:
    server: nginx
    date: Sat, 23 Dec 2017 17:25:09 GMT
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    content-length: 829
    connection: keep-alive
    status: 404 Not Found
    x-request-id: 36a5b780-d160-45c3-b0ad-83f4ff35f519
    x-runtime: 0.003306
    accept-ranges: bytes
    x-varnish: 1432272046
    age: 0
    via: 1.1 varnish
    cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    pragma: no-cache
    x-cache: MISS
```

One weird thing I noticed is that the request is actually being sent to a different URL (url.com/shop) instead of what I explicitly wrote (url.com/shop/123123/add) (The page does redirect to url.com/shop though so it might be normal).

What is going on? Thanks.

Also, is it safe to send requests like this to "well-known" sites? Can they detect if the request is made by code or by a user? Is there any way to circumvent this detection? (This is optional, but if you know please respond)